# How to set scrlttr2 refvpos automatically based on address length

Tags: koma-script, lengths, letters

I am creating an letter options (lco) file that I will use for multiple letters. The `scrlttr2` class is designed for a fixed placement of the address field, and places the date at a fixed position from the top of the page (`refvpos`). I would like to change this so that `refvpos` is automatically adjusted based on the height of the address. This example results in the date and opening of the letter colliding with the address:

```
\documentclass[paper=letter]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\areaset{6.5in}{9in}

\KOMAoptions{parskip=full,refline=dateleft,fromalign=right}

\makeatletter
\@setplength{toaddrvpos}{0.5in}
\@setplength{refvpos}{1.5in}
\makeatother

\date{16 February 2012}

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{Dr.~Leo Lion\\Fordstan University\\Room 50\\1600 Pennsylvania Ave\\Somewhere\\United States of America}
\opening{Dear Sir,}
This is a test.
\closing{Sincerely yours}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Can I fix this so that the date will always be one `\baselineskip` after the address, regardless of whether the address is two lines or ten?

Comment: You would have to calculate the height before starting the letter. And the height of the address field is preset, too.

Comment: I wouldn't mind doing something like `\newcommand{\address}{Dr.~Leo Lion...}... \begin{letter}{\address}`. If I do that, is there a way to calculate the height of address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could redefine the letter command like this:

```
\let\oldletter\letter
\renewcommand\letter[1]{%
  \newdimen\height%
  \setbox0=\vbox{#1}%
  \height=\ht0 \advance\height by \dp0%
  \@setplength{toaddrheight}{\height}%
  \@setplength{refvpos}{\useplength{toaddrvpos}}%
  \@addtoplength{refvpos}{\useplength{toaddrheight}}%
  \@addtoplength{refvpos}{2\baselineskip}%
  \oldletter{#1}%
}
```

It places the address in a vbox, calculates its height, sets the height of the address field and finally calculates the resulting refvpos as a sum of
toaddrvpos+toaddrheight+2baselineskip.

Hope it helps.